# Read text file from Native code in Android project

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native-code

I searched for the similar information and can't find a clear solution. So I make inquiry here.
I like to read a text file from my native code.
I have two approaches.
(1)First file path is taken in Java and pass to native code as

```
In Java
File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                  String att =  "attr.names";
                  String tree =  "face.tree";
                  File mAttClass = new File(cascadeDir, att);
                  File mTree = new File(cascadeDir, tree); 
                  mNativeDetector.CreateNativeObject_Tree(mAttClass.getAbsolutePath(), mTree.getAbsolutePath());
                  mAttClass.delete();
                  mTree.delete();



In Native C
    void   GetNames(char *Fn)
    /*  ---------  */
    {
        LOGD("Enter getnames \n");
        FILE *Nf, *fopen();
        char Buffer[1000];
        DiscrValue v;
        int AttCeiling=100, ClassCeiling=100, ValCeiling;

        /*  Open names file  */


        if ( ! ( Nf = fopen(Fn, "r") ) )
            Error(0, Fn, "");

     }
```

This method make error as "Can't open file from /data/data/com.test.pck/app_cascade/attr.names".

(2) The second method is , the file (attr.names) is located in the same folder as source file in JNI folder. Then load using

```
if ( ! ( Nf = fopen(Fn, "r") ) )
                Error(0, Fn, "");
```

The error is "Can't open file from attr.names".

How can I read that text file from my native C code.

EDIT 1:
As discussions below. I need to use openRawResources() to get a file descriptor, offset, and size.
I tried to implement as follow.

```
  int rID = resources.getIdentifier("com.test.pkg:raw/"+attr.names, null, null); 
    InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(rID);
     File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String temp;
    File mCascadeFile = null;
    temp =  xmlarray[l] + ".xml";
    mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, temp);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile); 
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
     int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
           os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
      is.close(); 
      os.close();
```

Now it works.

Thanks

Comment: The first approach is the right idea, but you probably have some problem with the detail  of implementation.  Do you ever create the directory and file?  "new File()" creates a Java object to represent a file, **but does not create a file or directory on disk** - you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, yes I have "attr.names" and "face.tree" files in res/raw folder.

Comment: Well, that would explain your difficulty.  There's no res/raw folder on the device.  The actual filesystem locations used in your first attempt can probably work *if you write something there at runtime*.  If you want to use res/ instead you have to realize it is no longer a file at runtime, but a (read-only) android-unique data source with its own API.  You'd have to check if there's a native interface to resources.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use openRawResources() to get a file descriptor, offset, and size. Any idea why bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) doesn't reach to EOF.

Comment: Sorry it works. Can please answer?